# Finding vector for supremum norm of matrix

Tags: matrices, vectors, normed-spaces

Is it possible to find a vector $w$ under the constraint $|w|=1$ such that the euclidean norm $|Aw|$ is maximized, where $A$ is a matrix?

Comment: For an arbitrary matrix, it is possible to obtain it computationally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\omega_* = \underset{\omega}{\arg\max} \|A\omega\|$ subject to $\|\omega\| =1$. The Lagrangian is $$L(\omega,\lambda) = \|A\omega\|^2 + \lambda(1 - \|\omega\|^2) \Rightarrow\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \omega} = 2A^TA\omega - 2 \lambda \omega .$$ Setting $\left.\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \omega}\right|_{\omega = \omega_*}=0$ gives 
\begin{align}
A^TA\omega_* = \lambda \omega_* 
\end{align}
Multiplying on the left by $\omega_*^T$, gives $\|A\omega_*\|^2 = \lambda \|\omega_*\|^2 = \lambda$.
Thus, $\omega_*$ is the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of $A^TA$.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. It's the eigenvector for the largest-modulus eigenvalue.

This works over the complex numbers -- for the reals, if the largest-modulus eigenvalue $c$ is not real, then its conjugate $\bar{c}$ is also an eigenvalue, and there's a rotation+scale with scaling factor $|c|$ that operates on some 2-plane, and any vector in this 2-plane will work as $w$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the modulus of an eigenvalue?

Comment: If the eigenvalue is a complex number $a + b i$, then the modulus is defined to be $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$; if the eigenvalue happens to be real (i.e., $b = 0$, then this becomes $|a|$).